# Making text white on an overlay

Tags: html, css

In my project, I have a div that serves as a background image. Within that, I have another div which serves as a black overlay over my background image. I want to Insert text onto my page. I set this texts colour to white, however when viewing it, the overlay makes the text look grey and not white.

Does anybody know how to make this text look completely white?

**Here is my code**:

```css
.bgDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 88vh;
  position: relative;
  background: url("https://image.pposili/djdd.com") no-repeat center center/cover;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div class="bgDiv">
  <div class="overlay">
  </div>
  //THE TEXT <span style=" font-weight: 400; font-size: 25px; margin-left: 200px; color: #ffffff;">TEST </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Your overlay is going over your text. Give your text a higher `z-index`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

The class 'overlay' is above your text. Therefore your text is below the overlay. You can fix this by giving your text a higher `z-index` i.e `z-index: 1;`